# How to copy headers from pandas dataframe to a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to iterate over the rows of a dataframe while still being able to reference the headers for each value

```
for index in range(len(df)):
    # ex [apple, strawberry]
    fruits_in_stock = generate_list_of_fruits(df.ioc[i])
    # ex [lettuce]
    vegetables_in_stock = generate_list_of_veg(df.ioc[i])
```

Right now I'm not able to call the headers after I pass a row to each of the methods

Input Dataframe

```
store_id    apple   orange   strawberry  carrot   broccoli  lettuce
susans_grocery      y        n       y       n       n       y  
kevins_grocery      n        y       n       n       y       y  
jamies_grocery      n        n       y       n       n       y
```

Current Output

```
store_id       susans_grocery
1              y
2              n
3              y
4              n
5              n
6              y
```

Desired Output

```
store_id       susans_grocery
apple          yes
orange         no
strawberry     yes
carrot         no
broccoli       no
lettuce        yes
```

How do I keep the headers there to reference later? Is there another method or data structure I should be using with pandas? Thanks!

Comment: Does `df.iloc[0]` work?

Comment: use: `df.iloc[0].T`

Comment: Both `df.iloc[0]` and `df.iloc[0].T` return the attributes (fruits/vegs) as integers, where I want them to be called as string from the original column name

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely iterate by row and get the index at the same time, for example:

```
for ix, r in df.iterrows():
    print(f'ix: {ix}, row: {r}')
```

Note how `row` is now a `Series` for each index `ix`.

You can also use: `df.T` is you want to see all the columns at once...

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.iterrows() to get the (index, row) tuple, in which row is used as Series.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    apple_stock = row.apple
    # put your logic code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just:

```
df[df['store_id']=='susans_grocery'].T


Out[5]: 
        index               0
0    store_id  susans_grocery
1       apple               y
2      orange               n
3  strawberry               y
4      carrot               n
5    broccoli               n
6     lettuce               y
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on suhas' approach if you want to do it all in one shot and rename the headers as the store_id

```
df = df.T.reset_index()
df.columns = df.iloc[0].to_list()
df.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Output

```
     store_id susans_grocery kevins_grocery jamies_grocery
1       apple              y              n              n
2      orange              n              y              n
3  strawberry              y              n              y
4      carrot              n              n              n
5    broccoli              n              y              n
6     lettuce              y              y              y
```